# What is the purpose of using an iterator in this function's return value?

Tags: c++, iterator, find

I am looking at a function for parsing through local addresses and am confused by the rationale behind choice for return value. The function is

```
bool p2p::isLocalHostAddress(bi::address const& _addressToCheck)
{
    // @todo: ivp6 link-local adresses (macos), ex: fe80::1%lo0
    static const set<bi::address> c_rejectAddresses = {
        {bi::address_v4::from_string("127.0.0.1")},
        {bi::address_v4::from_string("0.0.0.0")},
        {bi::address_v6::from_string("::1")},
        {bi::address_v6::from_string("::")}
    };

    return find(c_rejectAddresses.begin(), c_rejectAddresses.end(), _addressToCheck) != c_rejectAddresses.end();
}
```

I understand the actual code of the return value, whereby std::find goes through the set looking for `_addressToCheck` but what is the reasoning behind comparing it with the set's end iterator?  Wouldn't the same logic in this case be implemented by listing the return value as

```
return find(c_rejectAddresses.begin(), c_rejectAddresses.end(), _addressToCheck) != NULL;
```

Comment: Maybe, the `find` method returns the end iterator if the item wasn't found.

Comment: [That is exactly what `std::find()` does](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find).  It searches the input container starting at the first iterator, up to but not including the second iterator. If the item is found, an iterator to that item is returned.  If the item is not found, the second iterator is returned.  This allows `std::find()` (and all of the other STL algorithms) to be container-agnostic

Comment: The concept of `NULL` doesn't make sense for an iterator. An iterator will point to either a valid element of a container or the container's `end()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what is the reasoning behind comparing it with the set's end iterator?

[`std::find()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) takes two iterators as input, searching from the first iterator up to but not including the second iterator. If the item is found, an iterator to the item is returned.  If the item is not found, the second iterator is returned.  Since `end()` is being passed in as the second iterator, the return value has to be compared to `end()` to know if the address was found or not.

> Wouldn't the same logic in this case be implemented by listing the return value as
>
> ```
> return find(c_rejectAddresses.begin(), c_rejectAddresses.end(), _addressToCheck) != NULL;
> ```

No, it would not.  That implies that `std::find()` returns a pointer, or at least an integer where 0 represents "not found".  That is not the case with many containers.  STL algorithms use iterators so they can be container-agnostic.

Answer (score 0):

It makes the return value compatible with other algorithm functions, meaning they can be embedded into each other.

```
auto found = find(list.begin(), list.end(), itemToFind);

for_each(list.begin(), found, doSomething);
```

Potentially not the most useful example.  But, it's easier to get the value from an iterator than to get an iterator from a value if need be.